# Do I have to install a module to authenticate users?

Tags: sails.js

As I have just installed sails, and created a new app, how would I authenticate users? do I have to install a module? what about authorization? are those two things built within the framework?

If those are not out of the box, then, which modules are recommend to go with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit the site node-machine.org and there are a few options. Node Machine is maintained by the creator of Sails and his team. If you're just getting started with Sails, I would try using this machinepack:

http://node-machine.org/machinepack-sessionauth